# NodeMCU HTTP Module HTTP.POST() Request Body Arguments

Tags: json, lua, esp8266, nodemcu

Can someone please advise me how to write the body of the http.post() request to read values from the attached sensors on the ESP8266?

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION);
wifi.sta.config("ssid","pwd")
local sensorPin = adc.read(0)

http.post('url',
  'Content-Type: application/json\r\n', 
  '"humidity":sensorPin'
  ,function(code, data)
    if (code < 0) then
      print("HTTP request failed")
    else
      print(code, data)
    end
  end)
```

How can I read values from the attached sensors on the GPIO pins and put that as the value for the "key":"value" pair in the body of the post request?

Comment: Do you need any more feedback here?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand *what exactly* your problem is, sorry. Is it how to [read GPIO values](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/gpio/), is it dealing with the [ADC](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/adc/), is it [sending data in an interval](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/tmr/),  or is it with string concatenation in Lua,  or?

So, here's a short snippet that'll fix your code:

```
url = 'url'
jsonContentTypeHeader = 'Content-Type: application/json\r\n'

http.post(url, jsonContentTypeHeader,
  '{"humidity":' .. adc.read(0) .. '}', function(code, data)
    if (code < 0) then
      print("HTTP request failed")
    else
      print(code, data)
    end
  end)
```

If you need to encode more JSON data then there's a [dedicated module](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/sjson/) for that.

It's also worth noting that `wifi.sta.config("ssid", "pwd")` is asynchronous (as are many NodeMCU functions) and you need to hold back network calls until you got an IP address. We have a [template for that in our docs](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/upload/#initlua) as well.